# Continuity with respect to a dominant metric

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Here is the definition I am working with.

> Let $\rho'$ and $\rho''$ be metrics on $X$. We say that $\rho''$ dominates $\rho'$ if there exists a $C \geq 0$ such that for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$,
> $$
> \rho'(x_1, x_2) \leq C \rho''(x_1, x_2).
> $$

I am trying to solve this problem using this definition.

> If $\rho'$ and $\rho''$ are metrics on $X$, with $\rho''$ dominating $\rho'$. Let $Y$ be another metric space.
>
> (a) If a map of sets $X \to Y$ is continuous with respect to $\rho'$, then it is continuous with respect to $\rho''$. \smallskip
>
> (b) If a map $Y \to X$ is continuous with respect to $\rho''$, then it is continuous with respect to $\rho'$.

Here is my attempt.

> (a) Incrementing $C$ if necessary, we can assume without loss of generality that $C > 0$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in X$. As $f: X \to Y$ is continuous with respect to $\rho'$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x' \in X$, $\rho'(x,x') < \delta$ implies $\rho_Y (f(x), f(x')) < \epsilon$. Set $\delta' = \frac{\delta}{C}$ and suppose that $\rho''(x,x') < \delta'$. Then $C \rho'' (x,x') < C \delta' = \delta$, so
> $$
> \rho'(x,x') \leq C \rho'' (x, x') < \delta,
> $$
> and because $\rho'(x,x') < \delta$, we have
> $$
> \rho_Y (f(x), f(x')) < \epsilon, 
> $$
> so $f$ is continuous with respect to $\rho''$.

I'm stuck on how to prove (b). I can choose a $\delta$ to make $\rho_Y (f(y) f(y')) < \epsilon$ when $\rho''(y,y') < \delta$, and I have
$$
\rho'(y,y') \leq C \rho''(y,y') < \delta. 
$$
I'll choose a $\delta'$ and assume $\rho'(y,y') < \delta'$, but that doesn't let me say anything about $\rho''$.

I would appreciate a hint on how to proceed with (b) and some feedback on (a).

Comment: In b) you forgot that $f$ maps $Y$ to $X$, no the other way around.

Comment: That helps a lot. Thanks! Does the proof of (a) look ok?

Comment: Yes, proof of a) is OK.

Comment: Let $T_d$ be the topology generated by a metric $d$. Prove that if $p''$ dominates $p'$ then $T_{p'} \subseteq T_{p''}.$ Show that any $y$ in an open $p''$-ball $B_{p''}(x,r/C)$ belongs to $B_{p'}(x,r).$